# Conjecture concerning modular arithmetic

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, factorial, conjectures

Below $0\notin\mathbb N$. I want a proof or a counter-example of the following (corrected) conjecture:

> Suppose $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $n\in\mathbb N$ and suppose
>   $kn+ap=m!$, where $ap<kn$, for some $a,k,m\in\mathbb N$, then there are
>   $k^{\prime},a^{\prime}\in\mathbb N$ such that $k^{\prime}n+a^{\prime}p=(m+1)!$, where $a^{\prime}p<k^{\prime}n$.

A more simple way to write the conjecture is (with some abuse of language):

Suppose $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $n\in\mathbb N$ and suppose 
$p|(m!\pmod n)$, then $p|((m+1)!\pmod n)$

Comment: So $n=ap$, and $p(ka+1)=m!$, so $m>p$.

Comment: What if $n=1$? What would $p$ be?

Comment: @KennyLau, I understand the first part of the first comment, but if $p$ is a prime factor of $n$, then obviously $n>1$.

Comment: Well, you did not put that obvious constrain in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *corrected* conjecture is true.

> Suppose $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $n\in\mathbb N$ and suppose
>   $kn+ap=m!$, where $ap<kn$, for some $a,k,m\in\mathbb N$, then there are
>   $k^{\prime},a^{\prime}\in\mathbb N$ such that $k^{\prime}n+a^{\prime}p=(m+1)!$, where $a^{\prime}p<k^{\prime}n$.

Taking $k'=(m+1)k$ and $a'=a(m+1)$ works since
$$k'n+a'p=(m+1)kn+a(m+1)p=(m+1)(kn+ap)=(m+1)!$$
and
$$ap\lt kn\implies ap(m+1)\lt kn(m+1)\implies a'p\lt k'n$$